# Where is log 13 in The Swapper?

Tags: the-swapper

I've just started playing the indie game "The Swapper" (I'm hooked—it's *very* good), and am a couple hours in.  I was looking through the story logs (pieces of written text from the in-game characters), I've just realized that I don't have #13.  I've gotten all logs in order (barring that one apparently), and I have all the way through #23.  There aren't any markers on my map from areas I've already been.

Are you supposed to get each log item in order?  Does it show up later, or should I circle back?  *Is* there a log #13?

(*hattip* to the developers, this is a beautiful game.)

Comment: I don't have the rep to tag this title appropriately, so if you do, feel free to create a 'the-swapper' tag.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Log 13 can be found at entrance to the "bottom" puzzle room of the **Metaphysics** area.

Here's a clipping of the map showing the position of the terminal relative to the long range teleporter in metaphysics, you can access the location via the middle of the three mini teleporters on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the game highlighted a the location for log #13 on the map.  Hope this helps!